# Custom highlighting with Eclipse/Python?

Tags: python, eclipse, syntax-highlighting

Can you think of some way to realize custom source code highlighting in Eclipse/Pydev?
I'd like to highlight some tokens that are usually not distinguished.

Is there a way to do change the highlighting in Eclipse and/or Pydev? I mean not just change colors, but really introduce new elements.
Or can I incorporate pygments into Eclipse?
Or if all this is hard, what is the easiest way to use another editor with pygments? Can I even embed another editor in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the keywords are not currently customizable.

(it's hard-coded at org.python.pydev.editor.PyCodeScanner)

You can grab the code and modify yourself...

I don't know of any attempt to integrate an eclipse editor with pygments, but I guess it could be possible.